# Trigger Odoo's Scheduled Action During Specific Hours (e.g. everyday every 1AM to 6AM)

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I want to have Scheduled Action that executes one after another from 1AM to 6AM everyday.

How can I achieve this?

Since the only menus I have are "Execute Every" and "Next Execution Date" I do not know how can I mention the specific hours range. I am using Odoo 11.

Comment: Do you have multiple actions or one action which should be repeated every x min from 1AM to 6AM?

Comment: One action that is executed from 1AM to 6AM. If the action finishes at 2AM it executed again.

Comment: That's not possible with Odoo Vanilla. So you need a customization for it. I didn't find a custom module, but i only looked into the OCA repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wrapper action which is scheduled to run more frequently.

```
def action_function():
    # you will need to store a value (is_running: True|False) in the database, maybe in ir.config_parameter
    if current_hour not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
        return None
    elif is_running:
        return None
    else:
        # Mark that the action is in process, have to commit to the database
        is_running = True
        self.env.cr.commit()
        # Then call your actual action function 
        do_some_real_thing()
        # Mark that the action is done
        is_running = False
```

Basically, the wrapper action of below steps repeats frequently like every 10 minutes.

- Check the time, if not between 1am and 6am, do nothing;
- Check if the action is already running, if yes, do nothing;
- Else, mark that the action as in process, and do the actual thing,
  once done, mark the action as finished.